# Word for desire to be recognized as super productive by others?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase for the desire to be recognized as very productive on everything one is responsible for?

Perhaps sometimes it could be a motivation for an overachiever. Or other times it could be a cause of depressive symptoms for not being able to do so.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is *Stakhanovite*, named for the Soviet coal miner [Alexey Stakhanov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksei_Grigorievich_Stakhanov) who reportedly produced 14 times his quota.

Not all the connotations are positive.

Answer (score 1):

I would say while an individual might in fact be "very productive in everything," the desire for recognition might be described as

> **egotistical** from **egotism** *noun* : 2 an exaggerated sense of self-importance :  conceit —

from m-w.com

related:

[image: EGOT necklace]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the word **dignity** might work here.  If a person is not an **attention-whore** and they work for trying to be truly productive than I think dignity is a big factor.

> the state or quality of being worthy of honor or respect.

Answer (score 0):

A term that has come to denote someone who is constantly seeking recognition could be 'prima donna', which is not an English word. I must, however, admit that I have seldom heard it applied to production workers! It also usually implies that the person concerned is apt to get upset over minor problems, the word for which also escapes me. Metaphors include 'putting on one's parts', 'throwing one's toys out of the pram' etc.